# react-navigation installation and first usage

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have use react-native, the version is `"version": "0.57.1"`. I have installed react-navigation via:

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

The react-navigation version is `react-navigation@3.4.0`. The content of app.js file is below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
// import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

This sample works fine on expo. But when I run third line, an error occurs.

> [16:57:50] While trying to resolve module `react-navigation` from file
>   `/home/ubuntu/workspace/App.js`, the package
>   `/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-navigation/package.json`
>   was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a
>   `main` module field that could not be resolved
>   (`/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js`.
>   Indeed, none of these files exist: [16:57:50]  [16:57:50]   *
>   `/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
>   [16:57:50]   *
>   `/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js/index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is odd you should not need to install react navigation specifically this should be installed automatically when making an expo project I would recommend deleting your node-modules and installing again with the following

```
rm -rf node_module && npm install
npm audit fix 
expo start
```

If this doesn’t do the trick try making a new project and just copy your class to it hope this helps

Comment: The guide is confused me :/ https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation